# Same label multiple times in one image - Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to create a tf model, which can detect any handwriting in any image. In order to do that, i made the labels in all train pictures with just one label: edit.
It means, one image can have this labels many times.

After many hours of training using cpu i did't get the expected result. The model can't see any of the blocks i gave before training.

I'm using the following model:

```
http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/efficientdet_d6_coco17_tpu-32.tar.gz
```

Is the problem that i'm labeling one image with one label multiple times?

Could be the problem of using cpu instead of gpu? I have currently one gpu with 4gb and it seems not enough.
i trained the model with 2000 steps and learning_rate was 0.006. should i train it to be more than that?

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advanced.

##### Edit

Following the is a screenshot from tensorboard of the trained model:

[image: tensorboard of trained model]

Answer (score 0):

#### CPU vs GPU

GPU has the only advantage that the training is faster. It shouldn't have any effect on the expected result. It just takes longer. Though, for some models, the difference could be large. Monitoring your training might give you more insight.

#### Training monitoring

What does it mean you did not get the expected result? How was it different from what you expected?

I suggest you use some kind of monitoring, such as Tensorboard to monitor both the loss and metrics of the training and validation dataset if you do not already do so. This will give you invaluable information about the training in real-time.

#### Pipeline debugging

When your model seems not to be learning anything, you must start debugging.
You can follow the following steps to make sure that none of those is your problem: https://blog.slavv.com/37-reasons-why-your-neural-network-is-not-working-4020854bd607

I especially like to overfit the model on a single batch. This test tells me whether my algorithmic pipeline is correct, including preprocessing, the model, and the evaluation. The result should be that evaluation on the single training batch should give you a very good score, while for the rest of the data the score will be poor since the model will be overfitted on the single batch.

#### Problem definition

Sometimes, it is possible that the problem is wrongly defined. Can you clarify what your labels are? I do not fully understand. If it is a common problem, then you can search the internet to see the inspiration for how it is usually defined.

### EDIT

#### Loss functions

In general, you want all your loss functions to go down. In your case, they go up in the first few hundred steps, which might not necessarily indicate that there's something wrong because sometimes it takes a short time in the beginning before the training stabilizes. Nonetheless, the triangles indicate that the loss was NaN. That means that there is something wrong. I can recommend using the `tf.keras.callbacks.TerminateOnNaN` callback to detect the NaNs in your loss immediately, which will terminate your training promptly.

#### Metrics

From the loss functions themselves, it hard to tell what is the model's performance. In every machine learning task, you have to be able to understand the performance of a model. Metrics are used exactly for that purpose. In this case (object detection), I suggest using **IoU** to determine how well the predicted box overlaps with the target one, and `precision` and `recall` for evaluating the performance of your binary classification of whether the predicted box contains hand-written text or not.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. The expected result that the model can find the handwriting spots on the image. When i give the model an image the model can’t detect any labels. 
I just have one label i named :edit. This label was set for any handwriting spot in any image in train set. One image can get this labels many times. (Because handwriting could be in different spots in the image and also it has many shapes)

Comment: I will post here the metrics of loss and learning rates. It seems to be fine because loss rate is tending to be nano and learning rate is raising.

Comment: The problem sounds to me like object detection, which is typically defined by rectangles using coordinates in the target image. Is each of your handwriting spots defined in this way or differently? And yes, please do include the loss during training.

Comment: I have edited my post and added a screenshot of the losses from tensorboard. 
I have defined the handwriting spots in rectangels and gave every rectangels the label: edit. I also made the labeling for each letter of the handwriting. 
if the handwritng has the word for example: "done" --> this has 4 labels of the label edit. 
My target is, if any letter with handwriting has been detected, the model just has to tell me there is a handwriting.

Comment: @El-Salatinie See my edited answer. What strikes me is that you created the labels yourself. How big is your dataset? In any case, you should try training the model on a single batch and make sure that it overtrains. It should overtrain in very few  
training steps. If it doesn't, something is wrong with your code.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I've no experience with tensorflow before that's why i couldn't release that the performance of model is not correct. My Dataset is about 35 files with many edit labels.
What you mean with single batch training? if you mean batch_size in pipeline_config then it was set to 1.

Comment: @El-Salatinie Batch size is the number of samples (e.g., images) used for a single pass through the network, after which the model (network) is updated. Batch size is typically set to 16 and higher. Dataset of 35 files is definitely small for a neural network to learn. NNs require huge amounts of data. You would need at least thousands. Two suggestions: 1) try to learn something about training neural networks and experiment with existing datasets, Tensorflow docs contain many simple examples. 2) search online for existing datasets for your problem. And have fun.